# Moving the contents of a view rather than the view itself

Tags: objective-c

I am creating my own slide menu which is pretty simple.

I am creating a subview, adding it to the view and then sliding the `self.view` to the right by `170px` which reveals the new subview (named `secondView`).

However, none of the buttons on the new view are clickable after moving the `self.view` to the right (as they were before I did this). So I image that because the view has moved, the view is the clickable region of the app.

Is there a way to move the content across as opposed to the view to allow the new view to be clickable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is:
Touches outside of a view's frame never trigger events to its subviews.
I mean, touches outside of `self.view.frame`  never trigger event to `secondView` that is one of subviews of `self.view`.
see: [Event Handling Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/event_delivery_responder_chain/event_delivery_responder_chain.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH4-SW4)

You can `[self.view.window addSubview:secondView]` and move both `self.view` and `secondView`.

```
[self.view.window addSubView:secondView];

CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
CGRect secondFrame = secondView.frame;
viewFrame.origin.x += 170;
secondFrame.origin.x += 170;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
    self.view.frame = viewFrame;
    secondView.frame = secondViewFrame;
}];
```

**Note**:
Above code may cause troubles if `self` is not window's rootViewController. e.g. in `UINavigationController`.